# How to pass the current Spring Boot version to a custom property

Tags: spring-boot

I would like to get the current Spring Boot version and pass it to a custom property.
Something like this:

```
my.custom.property=${howtogetthecurrentspringbootversion?}
```

I tried:

```
my.custom.property=${spring-boot.version}
```

```
my.custom.property=${spring-boot.formatted-version}
```

Unfortunately, it is not resolving to anything, I get the whole ${xxx} without any value (expecting a version, such as 3.2.0).

How to get the current Spring Boot version, and pass it to a custom property?